MSVC global variables initialization order
MSVC 2022 VERSION.
If i use MFC static lib,i can use #pragma init_seg(lib) to change global variables initialization order. make my local global variables earlier than the lib.
and Now I have to use MFC dynamic library,Is there any way to initialize my global variables before the dll.
even #pragma init_seg(compiler) was useless. How can I implement Local programs to initialize global variables earlier than the global variables in MFC DLLS?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
